# Nodejs global property interception

Tags: node.js, v8

Im looking for a way to intercept access to object properties in nodejs. In particular, my goal is not to define a proxy for each object manually, but to enable this interception globally, for each newly created object.

That means, for every single access to a property (whether it exists or not) on every single object, whether it was instantiated by me or not, should go through some interception logic.

Example:

```js
// code that sets up interception

let o = {}
o.xyz // => trigger interception mechanism
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such behavior would not be in compliance with the JavaScript spec.